# Error on specific search query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website ongrounds.com there is a search bar on top when ever I search for word "best" it generates following error

> Warning: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s) AS relevance FROM hotaru_posts WHERE (post_status = %s OR post_status = %s)' at line 1 in /home2/onground/public_html/libs/extensions/ezSQL/mysql/ez_sql_mysql.php on line 264
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in `/home2/onground/public_html/content/plugins/bookmarking/libs/BookmarkingFunctions.php` on line 132

But when I search any other word except "best" the search plugin works fine and it shows results. I do not know why it is showing error on word "best". Please help.

SEARCH PLUGIN CODE:

```
class Search
```

{
    /**
     * Add permissions and register search widget
     */
    public function install_plugin($h)
    {
        // Permissions
        $site_perms = $h->getDefaultPermissions('all');
        if (!isset($site_perms['can_search'])) { 
            $perms['options']['can_search'] = array('yes', 'no');
            $perms['can_search']['default'] = 'yes';
            $h->updateDefaultPermissions($perms);
        }

```
    // widget
    $h->addWidget('search', 'search', '');  // plugin name, function name, optional arguments
} 

/**
 * Get search results
 */
public function theme_index_top($h)
{
    // Get page title
    if ($h->cage->get->keyExists('search')) { 
        $title = stripslashes(htmlentities($h->cage->get->sanitizeTags('search'),ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'));
        $h->pageTitle = make_name($title);
        $h->subPage = 'search';
        $h->pageType = 'list';
        $h->pageName = 'search';
    }
} 


/**
 * Displays "Search!" wherever the plugin hook is.
 */
public function search_box($h)
{
    $h->displayTemplate('search_box', 'search');
}


/**
 * Displays "Search!" wherever the plugin hook is.
 */
public function widget_search($h)
{
    $h->displayTemplate('search_box', 'search');
}


/**
 * Use the search terms to build a filter
 */
public function bookmarking_functions_preparelist($h, $vars)
{
    if ($h->cage->get->keyExists('search')) 
    {
        $return = $vars['return'];  // are we getting the count or the result set?
        $orig_search_terms = stripslashes($h->cage->get->sanitizeTags('search'));
        $search_terms = $orig_search_terms;

        if ($search_terms)
        {
            // fetch select, orderby and filter...
            $prepared_search = $this->prepareSearchFilter($h, $search_terms, $return);
            extract($prepared_search);

            $h->vars['orig_search'] = $orig_search_terms; // use this to re-fill the search box after a search

            $h->vars['orig_search_terms'] = $orig_search_terms; // used in the breadcrumbs function

            return true;    
        }
    }

    return false;    
}

/**
 * Prepare search filter
 */
public function prepareSearchFilter($h, $search, $return = 'posts')
{
    $search_terms = strtolower($search);
    $search_terms = explode(" ", $search_terms);
    $search_terms = array_iunique($search_terms);

    $search_terms_clean = '';
    $full_text = true; // Do a full text (better) search if all terms are longer than 3 characters
    foreach($search_terms as $search_term) {

        if ($this->isStopword($search_term)) {
            continue; // don't include this in $search_terms_clean
        }

        if (strlen(trim($search_term)) < 4) {
            $full_text = false;
        }

        $search_term = trim($h->db->escape($search_term));

        // if the urlencoded term contains a percent sign, we can't use a full text search
        if (strpos(urlencode($search_term), '%') !== false) {
            $full_text = false;
        }

        $search_terms_clean .= $search_term . " ";
    }

    // Undo the filter that limits results to either 'top', 'new' or archived (See submit.php -> sub_prepare_list())
    if (isset($h->vars['filter']['post_status = %s'])) { unset($h->vars['filter']['post_status = %s']); }
    if (isset($h->vars['filter']['post_archived = %s'])) { unset($h->vars['filter']['post_archived = %s']); }

    // filter to top or new stories only:
    $h->vars['filter']['(post_status = %s OR post_status = %s)'] = array('top', 'new');

    $select = ($return == 'count') ? "count(*) AS number " : "*";
    if ($full_text) {
        $h->vars['select'] = array($select . ", MATCH(post_title, post_domain, post_url, post_content, post_tags) AGAINST (%s) AS relevance" => trim($search_terms_clean));
        $h->vars['orderby'] = "relevance DESC";
        $h->vars['filter']["MATCH (post_title, post_domain, post_url, post_content, post_tags) AGAINST (%s IN BOOLEAN MODE)"] = trim($search_terms_clean); 
    } else {
        $h->vars['select'] = $select;
        $h->vars['orderby'] = "post_date DESC";
        $h->vars['filter_vars'] = array();
        $where = $this->explodeSearch($h, 'post_title', $search_terms_clean) . " OR ";
        $where .= $this->explodeSearch($h, 'post_url', $search_terms_clean) . " OR ";
        $where .= $this->explodeSearch($h, 'post_content', $search_terms_clean);
        $where = '(' . $where . ')';
        $h->vars['filter'][$where] = $h->vars['filter_vars'];
    }

    $prepared_search = array('select' => $h->vars['select'], 'orderby' => $h->vars['orderby'], 'filter' => $h->vars['filter']);

    return $prepared_search;
}


/** Explode search for short words
 * 
 * @param string $column
 * @param string $search_terms
 * @return string (with " OR " stripped off the end)
 */
public function explodeSearch($h, $column, $search_terms)
{
    $query = '';

    foreach(explode(' ', trim($search_terms)) as $word){
        if ($word) {
            $query .= $column . " LIKE %s OR ";
            $search_term = urlencode(" " . trim($h->db->escape($word)) . " ");
            // escape all percent signs for use in LIKE query:
            $search_term = str_replace('%', '\%', $search_term);
            array_push($h->vars['filter_vars'], "%" . $search_term . "%");
        }
    }

    return substr($query, 0, -4);
}


/**
 * Is it a stopword?
 *
 *@return bool
 */
public function isStopword($word)
{
    $word_array = array();

     // list came from http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/MySQL_4.0.20_stop_word_list
    $stopwordlist = "things ii iii a able about above according accordingly across actually after afterwards again against ain't all allow allows almost alone along already also although always am among amongst an and another any anybody anyhow anyone anything anyway anyways anywhere apart appear appreciate appropriate are aren't around as aside ask asking associated at available away awfully be became because become becomes becoming been before beforehand behind being believe below beside besides best better between beyond both brief but by c'mon c's came can can't cannot cant cause causes certain certainly changes clearly co com come comes concerning consequently consider considering contain containing contains corresponding could couldn't course currently definitely described despite did didn't different do does doesn't doing don't done down downwards during each edu eg eight either else elsewhere enough entirely especially et etc even ever every everybody everyone everything everywhere ex exactly example except far few fifth first five followed following follows for former formerly forth four from further furthermore get gets getting given gives go goes going gone got gotten greetings had hadn't happens hardly has hasn't have haven't having he he's help hence her here here's hereafter hereby herein hereupon hers herself hi him himself his hither hopefully how howbeit however i'd i'll i'm i've ie if ignored immediate in inasmuch inc indeed indicate indicated indicates inner insofar instead into inward is isn't it it'd it'll it's its itself just keep keeps kept know knows known last lately later latter latterly least less lest let let's like liked likely little look looking looks ltd mainly many may maybe me mean meanwhile merely might more moreover most mostly much must my myself name namely nd near nearly necessary need needs neither never nevertheless new next nine no nobody non none noone nor normally not nothing novel now nowhere obviously of off often oh ok okay old on once one ones only onto or other others otherwise ought our ours ourselves out outside over overall own part particular particularly per perhaps placed please plus possible presumably probably provides que quite qv rather rd re really reasonably regarding regardless regards relatively respectively right said same saw say saying says second secondly see seeing seem seemed seeming seems seen self selves sensible sent serious seriously seven several shall she should shouldn't since six so some somebody somehow someone something sometime sometimes somewhat somewhere soon sorry specified specify specifying still sub such sup sure t's take taken tell tends th than thank thanks thanx that that's thats the their theirs them themselves then thence there there's thereafter thereby therefore therein theres thereupon these they they'd they'll they're they've think third this thorough thoroughly those though three through throughout thru thus to together too took toward towards tried tries truly try trying twice two un under unfortunately unless unlikely until unto up upon us use used useful uses using usually value various very via viz vs want wants was wasn't way we we'd we'll we're we've welcome well went were weren't what what's whatever when whence whenever where where's whereafter whereas whereby wherein whereupon wherever whether which while whither who who's whoever whole whom whose why will willing wish with within without won't wonder would would wouldn't yes yet you you'd you'll you're you've your yours yourself yourselves zero";

    $word_array = explode(' ', $stopwordlist);

    if (array_search($word, $word_array) == true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}


/**
 * Add RSS link to breadcrumbs
 */
public function breadcrumbs($h)
{
    if ($h->subPage != 'search') { return false; }

    $crumbs = "<a href='" . $h->url(array('search'=>urlencode($h->vars['orig_search_terms']))) . "'>\n";
    $crumbs .= $h->vars['orig_search_terms'] . "</a>\n ";

    return $crumbs . $h->rssBreadcrumbsLink('', array('search'=>urlencode($h->vars['orig_search_terms'])));
}


/**
 * If a search feed, set it up
 */
public function post_rss_feed($h)
{
```

Thank you

Comment: Would you mind posting the code used to generate the query?

Comment: Thank you for the response, please visit this link http://www.ongrounds.com/index.php?search=best

Comment: for one thing, i cant search for anything on your site unless logged in. This almost makes this question seem like a silly trick to get people to register on your site since in general your question does not seem possible. Especially since you do not provide any actual code or the whole query string.

Comment: I am really sorry kai Qing I did not noticed this (now you can search without registering)

Comment: I have attached the plugin code in the question.

Comment: I don't grasp the code, but from your error message, you have unreplaced `%s`'s where probably replaced strings should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this error will occur if the searched word ist a [Fulltext-stopword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-stopwords.html).

I cant tell you why this results in an error, but maybe this knowledge leads you into successfull investigations.

Comment: Thank you Dr.Molle you are genius, this is the problem but I do not know how to fix it :(

Comment: You could filter the stopwords from the input

Comment: Can you please give me an example? I am new to PHP coding.

Comment: As I see this is already implemented in your code(function isStopword() ). I guess the problem occurs if the search-term includes only words that are stopwords(so they all will be filtered). This will results in an empty searchstring and produces the error. So what you have to do: If the searchstring after filtering is empty, you have to cancel the search.